# id field truncated in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a 'report' function which provides a dropdown of options and a submit button. Once an option is selected, it passes the ID of that choice to another function called "generatePatientInfo($id=null)" which then generates a csv. My problem is that the ID is truncated after the first number. Single digit id's like 2,5,6,9 etc all work the way they're supposed to, but if the ID is say 2044 it truncates the id to 2 and brings up the information for the choice with the id of 2 and not 2044. It's perplexing and i'm not sure how to fix it. Below are my controller and view code for the action.

```
 function report(){
$this->set('alldrugs', $this->Drug->find('list', array(
  //'cache' => 'drugList',
  //'cacheConfig' => 'sql',
  'fields' => array('id', 'generic'),
  'order' => 'Drug.generic',
  'recursive' => -1,
)));
if (!empty($this->data['DrugCalls'])) {
  $this->Session->setFlash(sprintf($this->data['DrugCalls']['DrugList']['id']));
  //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'drugs','action'=>'generatePatientInfo',$this->data['DrugCalls']['DrugList']['id']));
  }
  }

  function generatePatientInfo($id=null) {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    // get drug info
    $drug = $this->Drug->read(
      array(
        'Drug.id', 'Drug.generic'
      ),
      $id
    );
    $this->set('drug',$drug);
    $patients = $this->Drug->query('SELECT patients.id, calls.id call_id, patients.first_name, patients.last_name, patients.phone, patients.email, calls.created '
      . 'FROM drugs, drug_lactation_links, lactation, calls, patients '
      . 'WHERE drugs.id = ' . $id . ' AND drugs.id = drug_lactation_links.drug_id AND '
      . 'drug_lactation_links.lactation_id = lactation.id AND lactation.call_id = calls.id AND calls.patient_id = patients.id '
      . 'UNION '
      . 'SELECT patients.id, calls.id call_id, patients.first_name, patients.last_name, patients.phone, patients.email, calls.created '
      . 'FROM drugs, drug_pregnancy_links, pregnancies, calls, patients '
      . 'WHERE drugs.id = ' . $id . ' AND drugs.id = drug_pregnancy_links.drug_id AND '
      . 'drug_pregnancy_links.pregnancy_id = pregnancies.id AND pregnancies.call_id = calls.id AND calls.patient_id = patients.id '
      . 'ORDER BY created DESC'
    );
    $this->set(compact('patients'));
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Patient contact information for ' . $drug['Drug']['generic']);
  }
```

Views:

```
<?php //report.ctp ?>
<div>

<?php echo $form->create('DrugCalls', array('url' => array('controller' => 'drugs', 'action' => 'report')));?>
<?php //echo $form->create('Patient Calls');?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><?php printf('Calls for Generic Report'); ?></legend>
  <?php
    echo $form->input('DrugList', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'DrugList', 'label' => 'Select generic drug:',
      'empty' => 'Select', 'options' => $alldrugs)
    );
    echo '<br />NOTE: Select a drug above to generate a list of patients who called about it.' .
          '<br/>' . 'The report will need to be imported into Excel.';
    echo $form->end(__('Submit', true));
  ?>
  </fieldset>
</div>



<?php
//generate_patient_info.ctp
// add the header row
$header = array('First Name','Last Name','Phone Number','Email');

$csv->addRow(array('Enter Generic: ' . $drug['Drug']['generic']));
$csv->addRow(array('Drug ID: ' . $drug['Drug']['id']));
$csv->addRow($header);

// add all the data
foreach($patients as $patient) {
  $csv->addRow(array(
    $patient[0]['first_name'],
    $patient[0]['last_name'],
    $patient[0]['phone'],
    $patient[0]['email'],
  ));
}
$csv->addRow(array());

// render the CSV file
echo $csv->render('Patients-list.csv');
?>
```

Comment: inside your `generatePatientInfo()` function do a `debug($id); exit;` - is the function actually being passed the correct ID? And using `Model::query` is generally bad practice as you can achieve 99% of what you need using Cake's ORM. If you use it anyway; make sure you properly sanitise `$id`

Comment: @Ross I know it's not getting the right id, what I don't know is why the id's get truncated like they do. They're all valid id's but it cuts them off after the first number. If it's a single digit, the generatePatientInfo function works correctly.

Comment: Yes, but does `$id` actually contain the correct number, and Cake is somehow corrupting it, or does `$id` arrive at your script already broken? That would suggests your javascript, or form is messing with the data. If `2044` is acutally being passed to the query, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Ross The generatePatientInfo() function is getting the wrong id. I set the dropdown to just show the id's and the report function to just output a flash message showing the id it received from the dropdown, and it's showing it cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed it down to the way I was accessing the dropdowns information. In my report function, I was accessing it incorrectly. I had to change it to: `$this->data['DrugCalls']['DrugList']` Instead of `$this->data['DrugCalls']['DrugList']['id']`